# Example of antecedent and consequent phrase with chords?

Tags: classical-music, musical-forms

I am having trouble understanding the antecedent phrase (ends with a weak cadence) and the consequent phrase (ends with a strong cadence) (first and second parts, respectively of the "period") in the abstract.  I understand the concepts of a half cadence (like an evaded or deceptive cadence?) and strong cadence (PAC)? But I am having trouble seeing it applied to a larger progression.  I also don't see how the melody ties into this.  Could you please provide a simple example in the key of C major so that I can finally understand how to use antecedent and consequent phrases in practice?

I apologize if you have answered this question before--I see that similar questions have been asked.  I am just not great at reading notation in keys besides C.  I hope you understand.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one in C major, found [here](https://mramusicplace.net/2016/02/26/what-are-antecedent-consequent-phrases-in-music/).

> Another popular example from classical music is the well-known theme
>   found in the final movement of Symphony No. 1 by Brahms. Once again,
>   the antecedent phrase begins on the tonic, which is C major, and ends
>   on the dominant.
>
> [image: antecedent phrase]
>
> This time, the consequent phrase not only has the same rhythm as its
>   antecedent cousin, it also has the same pitches. Only the last pitch
>   is different, and this is the only difference between the two phrases.
>   It manages to end on the tonic, bringing closure to the
>   antecedent-consequent pair.
>
> [image: Consequent phrase]